# How to find the location of modules for python3 and debug an ImportError

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pythonpath, pyperclip

I'm using Python 3.4.2 on a MacbookPro (10.9.5).  The code is from [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python by Al Sweigart](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter6/)  I have a weird error when trying to run a script in python3.
The code is below but I don't think it's the problem.  It might be a module path issue but not 100% sure from my debugging.

I can run the code in Idle but I can't run the code from cmd line, running with either shebang or python3 "name of script".

We can see below, that pip3 and python3 are both in /usr/local/bin.  We can also see the pyperclip module is installed.  However, when running the script from cmd line, it says it can't find the module, even though it's installed.

I ran this from my terminal:

```
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
$ pip3 freeze | grep clip
pyperclip==1.5.24
$ python3 pw.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pw.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ImportError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

However, in Idle, the code runs fine w/o giving the error of module not found:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Password for email copied to clipboard
>>>
```

Does anyone know what might be happening with my path or what other cmds I can run in my script or from the terminal to determine what's going on?

Test code below

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# pw.py - an insecure password locker program

import sys
import pyperclip

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6',
      'blog': 'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt',
      'luggage': '12345'}

account = "email"

if account in PASSWORDS:
   pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
   print ('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard')
else:
   print ('There is no account named ' + account)
```

Comment: Have your script print sys.path, and check those folders.

Comment: @SamuelLittley - thx for the tip.  it IS looking at 2 different locations but I don't know why.  It's looking at Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions 3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (working / Idle looks here) and /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (not working and looks empty. Terminal looks here).  Can you tell me how to make python3 from terminal look at the first locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the solutions:

```
export PYTHONPATH=//Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

before you run your script in terminal

OR 
Add this to your code (at the beginning) :

```
import sys;
sys.path.insert(0, "Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages")
```

OR (easiest and most effective since you only need to do this once)

Link `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages`:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can I still use the PYTHONPATH environment variable if I have both python2 and 3 installed?  I haven't tried yet b/c I'm afraid I might mess up more than I fix since I have both versions installed.

Comment: Then try the last solution :).